# How to update query param in Next js 14 app directory like <input type="text" onChange={updateQueryParam} />

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js14

Hey Guys I am stuck could you please help.
I want to update query param on input change handler.

**Points to be Noted**

1. I want the data with query params value parameter don't suggest code with parent to child OR child to parent data transfer like Props or callback hanlder.
2. As you update query params So they will be available instantly on Parent component with the functions you created.
3. If there are more query parameter, only value query parameter shoudl change other query params shoudl remain same

```
Text Input Child Component:

const TextInputComp = () => {
    function onInputChange () {
    /* Logic to update only value query param not any other one if exist more query param */
    }
return (
    <input type="text" onChange={onInputChange} />
)
```

```
Parent Comp:

function ParentComp  ()  {
    const [valueQueryParam,setValueQueryParam] = useState() /* only value Query param should capture in useState  */

    useEffect(()=>{
    /* Your Logic to get value query Param fom URL with every time it changes  */
    },[/* Your Dependency */])

    return(
        <div>
            <TextInputComp />
            {valueQueryParam} your realtime query param text 
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Please do not duplicate this question**

Comment: Do you use next.js or plain React? Do you use any state management systems e.g. redux?

Comment: I am using Next.js 14 app directory, The function doesn't need state management because I clearly say that I want a function that I can use everywhere in the app directory to get realtime query params value.

Comment: I understand. I asked just to see if the reloading will affect client state. I'm writing an answer right now

Comment: Thanks, will wait for your best suggestion

Answer (score 0):

First of all, There are three *main* types of routing/navigation:

- Hard Navigation
- Soft Navigation
- Shallow Navigation

Hard Navigation would not be the worst choice to update the search param with since it reloads the entire page, skip the browser cache, destroy client-side state, etc...

Still two types:

1. Soft Navigation:
   Reloads as less as needed from the page and keep the cached/static files.

> Good to know: Refreshing the page `onChange` is not a good UX. You can use `onBlur` instead

to push search param softly:

```js
import { useRouter, usePathname, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
// ...
const pathname = usePathname(); // let's get the pathname to make the component reusable - could be used anywhere in the project
const router = useRouter();
const currentSearchParams = useSearchParams();

function onInputBlur(event) {
  // let's assume we want to push the `query` searchParam
  const query = event.target.value;

  const updatedSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(currentSearchParams.toString())
  updatedSearchParams.set("query", query)

  router.push(pathname + "?" + updatedSearchParams.toString())
}
```

2. Shallow Navigation
   This type changes the URL without reloading the page

```js
const currentSearchParams = useSearchParams();

function onInputBlur(event) {
  const query = event.target.value;

  const updatedSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(currentSearchParams.toString())
  updatedSearchParams.set("query", query)

  window.history.pushState(null, "", "?" + updatedSearchParams.toString())
}
```

Keep away from the last option if you are using (a bit) old version of Next.js because it was introduced lately at `14.0.x` and been enabled by default since `14.1.0`. So, if anyone reads this answer and uses older next.js version this might not work as expected.

Comment: there is a side case I'm thinking of. -- If the component that consume searchParams doesn't refresh when the url changes let me know to tell how to make it refresh. (I didn't add this to the answer because I'm not sure if it does or not)

Comment: I want the code with onChange means realtime, I will use-debounce if any memory leaks occurs and I would need the realtime updated query param that I have to show as text which is missing, could you please edit these ?

Comment: the same, just use the function at `onChange` prop

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [`nuqs`](https://github.com/47ng/nuqs) was built to do (disclaimer: I'm the author).

There are a couple of things to watch out for when connecting a high-frequency update source (text input, `<input type="range">` slider) to the URL.

One is that browsers rate-limit calls to the History API. Around 20 calls per second for Chrome and Firefox, but Safari has much lower limits (1000 calls per 30s). So you'll want to throttle your updates.

The issue of throttling is that a controlled input will become out of sync with its state, and will result to a janky experience.

`nuqs` uses an internal state that updates as React.useState would, but defers and throttles updates to the URL in parallel, to reach eventual consistency.

Your example would then look like this:

```
'use client'

import { useQueryState, parseAsString } from 'nuqs'

const TextInputComp = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useQueryState(
    'search',
    parseAsString.withDefault('')
  )
  return (
    <input 
      type="text"
      value={search}
      onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value || null)
      // null clears the query key if the input is empty
    />
)
```

Then your parent component (or anything else in the tree) can use the same hook to read the value:

```
function ParentComp  ()  {
  const [search, setSearch] = useQueryState(
    'search',
    parseAsString.withDefault('')
  )
  return (
    <div>
      <TextInputComp />
      {search} your realtime query param text 
    </div>
  )
}
```

As a matter of fact, this exact use-case is showcased on the landing page demo: https://nuqs.47ng.com/?hello=AL+Faiz+Ahmed